# Export sql table with data that has commas to a csv file

Tags: mysql, export-to-csv

How do I export the sql table in mysql workbench to a .csv without separating every commas even in the column data?

Thanks!

**Solution**: One way is to use the **Table Data Export Wizard**. It worked for me.

Comment: Do you mean "how can I export as a CSV data which has commas in it?"

Comment: @tadman No, I have the sql table. I'm trying to export it to .csv by only choosing to split on certain commas.

Comment: I don't know what "split on certain commas" means without a lot more context. An example here would be very illuminating.

Comment: @tadman For example, say one of my columns contain addresses like "West Road, 12 West Coast, West State". and if I set my delimiter as ',' every commas will be split into new columns.

Comment: If you use a proper CSV export call that's not a problem. CSV columns can contain commas, it's in the [CSV specification](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180). Be sure to use the `ENCLOSED BY` option.